# Appending data column from one SFrame to another SFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graphlab, sframe

My training data `train` `SFrame` looks like this with 4 columns (the "Store" column is **non-unique** in this SFrame):

```
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
| Store |    Date    |  Sales  | Customers |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
|   1   | 2015-07-31 |  5263.0 |   555.0   |
|   2   | 2015-07-31 |  6064.0 |   625.0   |
|   3   | 2015-07-31 |  8314.0 |   821.0   |
|   4   | 2015-07-31 | 13995.0 |   1498.0  |
|   3   | 2015-07-20 |  4822.0 |   559.0   |
|   2   | 2015-07-10 |  5651.0 |   589.0   |
|   4   | 2015-07-11 | 15344.0 |   1414.0  |
|   5   | 2015-07-23 |  8492.0 |   833.0   |
|   2   | 2015-07-19 |  8565.0 |   687.0   |
|   10  | 2015-07-09 |  7185.0 |   681.0   |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+
[986159 rows x 4 columns]
```

Given a second `store` `SFrame` (the "Store" column is unique in this SFrame):

```
+-------+-----------+
| Store | StoreType |
+-------+-----------+
|   1   |     c     |
|   2   |     a     |
|   3   |     a     |
|   4   |     c     |
|   5   |     a     |
|   6   |     a     |
|   7   |     a     |
|   8   |     a     |
|   9   |     a     |
|   10  |     a     |
+-------+-----------+
```

I could attach the appropriate `StoreType` to my `train` `SFrame` by going through each row in the `train` and find the appropriate `StoreType` from `store` and then keep the column and ise `SFrame.add_column()` afterwards:

```
store_type_col = []
for row in train:
    row_store = row['Store']
    row_storetype = next(i for i in store if i['Store'] == row_store)['StoreType']
    store_type_col.append(row_storetype)

train.add_column(graphlab.SArray(store_type_col, dtype=str), name='StoreType')
```

To get:

```
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Store |    Date    |  Sales  | Customers | StoreType |
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   | 2015-07-31 |  5263.0 |   555.0   |   c 
|   2   | 2015-07-31 |  6064.0 |   625.0   |   a 
|   3   | 2015-07-31 |  8314.0 |   821.0   |   a
|   4   | 2015-07-31 | 13995.0 |   1498.0  |   c
|   3   | 2015-07-20 |  4822.0 |   559.0   |   a
|   2   | 2015-07-10 |  5651.0 |   589.0   |   a
|   4   | 2015-07-11 | 15344.0 |   1414.0  |   c
|   5   | 2015-07-23 |  8492.0 |   833.0   |   a
|   2   | 2015-07-19 |  8565.0 |   687.0   |   a
|   10  | 2015-07-09 |  7185.0 |   681.0   |   a
+-------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
[986159 rows x 5 columns]
```

But I'm sure there's a simpler and faster way to do this using `Graphlab`. The current method has a worst case of `O(n*m)` where n = no. of rows in `train` and m = no. of rows in `m`.

Imagine that my `store` `SFrame` has 8 columns which I want to append to `train`. The code above would be super inefficient.

**How else can I appending data column from one SFrame to another SFrame?** (Pandas solutions are welcomed too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a `join` operation.

`out = train.join(store, on = 'Store')`

Comment: Thanks!! That's a whole lot faster than the crazy `add_column()` =)